# PHP fwrite() not writing to log file

Tags: php, logging, fwrite

as one of my first PHP projects I'm creating an IP logging script that logs a user's IP address. For some reason my fwrite() function doesn't seem to be writing to my logfile.

Can someone help me out?

```
<?php
// IP Logger Script
// By Sam Lev
// sam@levnet.us
$iplogfile = 'iplog.txt';
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$webpage = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$timestamp = date('m/d/Y h:i:s');
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$fp = fopen($iplogfile, 'a+');
chmod($iplogfile, 0777);
fwrite($fp, '['.$timestamp.']: '.$ipaddress.' '.$webpage.' '.$browser. "\r\n");
fclose($fp);
echo "IP ADDRESS: $ipaddress <br />\n";
echo "TIMESTAMP: $timestamp <br />\n";
echo "BROWSER: $browser <br />\n";
echo "Information logged to server. <br />\n";
?>
```

iplog.txt is still blank after running the script. Everything echos out fine.

Thanks

Comment: Your code checks out. Make sure your file has write permissions. Either chmod `0644` or `0777`

Comment: Add `chmod($iplogfile, 0777);` after `$fp = fopen($iplogfile, 'a');`

Comment: I ran chmod 0777 'iplog.txt' from my ssh terminal. It's working now! Is this a permanent fix or do I need to make the changes to the code you listed above?

Comment: You don't have to do the chmod manually each time. Reset your file back to `0644` then try my suggestion above.

Comment: @Fred-ii- (forgot to tag you see above comment)

Comment: @Fred-ii- okay will do. This should theoretically make it so that if I ever need to re-config my server or change servers or something the code will still work... right?

Comment: Theoretically, yes it will. chmod is a standard server command which is not exclusive to PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code checks out and it's a permissions issue.

Either manually chmod your file to `0777`

or add `chmod($iplogfile, 0777);` after `$fp = fopen($iplogfile, 'a');`

**[chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)** is a standard server command which is not exclusive to PHP.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: I added the chmod line in my php code and manually set my permissions back to 0644. The file will no longer write to the log. I also added the + after the "a" in the $fp definition. (Not entirely sure what that does but someone suggested it). I've posted the updated code to the original question. Is there some reason chmod isn't working? Server running Ubuntu Server edition minimal.

Comment: @SamLev `a+` appends to the start of the file, as `a` is at the end of the file. As for it not working, that is strange. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about local web servers. Try moving the `chmod` command above `$fp = fopen($iplogfile, 'a+');` see if that will kick in.

Answer (score 6):

Shouldn't

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'a');
```

be

```
$fp = fopen($iplogfile, 'a');
```

? Because I don't see the definition of `$file`.

Comment: Still nothing. Could it be a permission error on my server or something? I uploaded the files via the webmin admin console...

Comment: @SamLev It is a permission issue. See my comments above.

Answer (score -1):

heres my code for logging if this helps but after adding code chmod the log files to 0777 or it wont work as adding the code doesn't make it work and will give php error hence why its not in the code btw you may have to create log files manually but easy enough this was for my site www.nzquakes.maori.nz thank you for the help

```
<!-- Below Code Logs ONLY User's IP Address & Time Stamp & Browser Info To http://www.example.com/logs/ip-address-mainsite.txt -->

<?php
$iplogfile = 'full path to your logs goes here eg http://www.example.com/logs/ip-address-mainsite.txt';
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//load the file
$file = file_get_contents($iplogfile);

//check to see if the ipaddress is already in the file
if ( ! preg_match("/$ipaddress/", $file )) {
//nope, log it!
$webpage = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$timestamp = date('d/m/Y h:i:s');
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$fp = fopen($iplogfile, 'a+');
fwrite($fp, '['.$timestamp.']: '.$ipaddress.' '.$browser. "\r\n");
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: this was for my site www.nzquakes.maori.nz